# Exclude specific file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file

Alright, I'm new to scripting and I'm trying to edit a batch script file that sends an email when a file with an extension of .ecl is in a folder longer than 5 min or so. But there are other files with a .ecl.part extension that get flagged and it sends an email instead of the .ecl files.  I'm curious if there is something I can add so that it will send an email when there are .ecl files in the folder for more than 5 min and ignore the .ecl.part files. I read one for someone with Linux who used [!(.extension to exclude)].extension not to exclude, I'm just wondering if this will work for my windows batch script. If it will work do I add it just like that or do I add it like this .extension not to exclude[!(.extension to exclude)]

Here is the part of the script in question:

```
     for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:, " %%a in ('forfiles /p z: /d +0 /s /m *.ecl /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @file,@ftime"') do (
     set  fnam=%%a
     set   fhr=%%b
     set  fmin=%%c
     set  fsec=%%d
     set fampm=%%e

     if "!fampm!" == "PM" if "!fhr!" neq "12" (set /a "fhr=!fhr!+12")
```

There is more of the script, I didn't set this up, and the person who did isn't being very helpful which is why I came here.

Comment: What happens when you try and run that sample script on your Windows machine?

Comment: Where is the `do` part from that for loop?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't show the do commands since everything works fine and it sends an email, I just want it to not send emails for files with the extension .ecl.part which are not relevant. Right now it sends an email for any file that is in the folder longer than 5 min with .ecl in the file name, so I'm getting emails for files that I want, the .ecl along with emails for files I don't want .ecl.part.

Comment: Also, the code doesn't do anything if I don't have files waiting in there. I guess I could create a file with the .ecl extension and leave it in the folder or point my batch script to a different location and test it. I was just wondering if what I found would work. Thanks again for the help. I added more of the code if that was needed.

Comment: So I tried the script with the [!(.part)] both before and after the *.ecl and neither work. All I want to do is prevent false positives, I think maybe it should be setup to see if it's a .ecl.part and not do anything but if it's a .ecl file it should send out an email. I just don't know how to go accomplishing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET savearea=c:\destdir
SET emldir=c:\sourcedir
ECHO.>"%savearea%\emlfiles.new"
DIR /b /a-d /on "%emldir%\*.eml" >>"%savearea%\emlfiles.new"
IF NOT EXIST "%savearea%\emlfiles.old" GOTO noold
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i IN ("%savearea%\emlfiles.new") DO (
FINDSTR /b /e "%%i" "%savearea%\emlfiles.old" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%i is MORE than 5 minutes old)
)
:noold
MOVE /y "%savearea%\emlfiles.new" "%savearea%\emlfiles.old" >nul
GOTO :eof
```

This script saves in %savearea% a sorted basic filelist of the *.eml files in %emldir% then compares the new list to the previous version. If the same filename appears in both, it will generate the message `%%i is MORE than 5 minutes old`

So - all you need to do is point `emldir` to wherever your .eml files reside, `savearea` to some safe directory, replace the message ECHOing with an email-sending command of your liking and schedule it to run each 5 minutes using task scheduler.

Comment: That's not really what I am trying to do here. I don't want to move the files, I am monitoring them, as there is another program that moves them. I am monitoring them to tell me if the other program is running or if I need to restart some services or a server for the files to move. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: The code is not moving anything. It generates a LIST of the files it finds and compares that list to the list generated in the previous run. Running the procedure every five minutes thus compares the two file lists and if there's a filename common to both lists, then it generates a message because if the same filename appears in each list then it was there 5 minutes ago and is still there now.

Comment: Alright that could work, I will keep it in mind. As of right now I'm just trying to edit the current batch script to prevent false positives. It generates emails and says they are .ecl but the fact is that the files are .ecl.part and I'm trying to get it to exclude the files with the .part on the end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although in my testing I find this not to be the case, it sounds like `forfiles`is evaluating wildcards against 8.3 short filenames on your computer.  You know how if you're in a directory containing both .doc and .docx files and you do a `dir *.doc`, the .docx files will be listed as well?  Same sort of thing.

So *.ecl is matching your .ecl.part files because in 8.3 notation they've got a .ecl extension.  You could either make sure `%fnam:~-4%==.ecl`, enclosing most of the guts of your `for` loop within an `if` statement; or you can use `find` or `findstr` to filter the output of `forfiles` as captured by the `for` loop.  Something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:, " %%a in (
    'forfiles /p z: /d +0 /s /m *.ecl /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @file,@ftime" ^| find /v /i ".part"'
) do (
    set  fnam=%%a
    set   fhr=%%b
    set  fmin=%%c
    set  fsec=%%d
    set fampm=%%e

    if "!fampm!" == "PM" if "!fhr!" neq "12" (set /a "fhr=!fhr!+12")
    rem etc.
```

Since `find /v` prints lines *not* matching its search, that should effectively filter out the .ecl.part files.  `find /v` works like `grep -v` in Linux.

---

You know, since my test cases don't seem to match the symptom you're describing, I am very curious to know whether simply replacing `if @isdir==FALSE` with `if @ext==\"ecl\"` would also prevent the .ecl.part files from being included.  But if you don't feel like experimenting to satisfy my curiosity, I totally understand.